# How to display a geojson to a geomap on grafana panel

Tags: grafana, geojson, multilinestring, geomap

I'm using MySQL and Grafana.
I wish to display a geojson field to a geomap but impossible to select geojson format.

The contains of geojson is a MultilineString.

What is best way to create a Panel on Grafana on my country and display all my geojson ?

Thanks for your help.

I tried :

- Orchestra Cities Map no
- GeoMap no